# How to convert scattered point to polygon in ArcGIS (e.g. Climate Zone)

Tags: shapefile, climate

I am new to ArcGIS and trying to crate global climate zone shapefile, covering both oceans and terrestrials.

As you can see in the attached pictures, the original data comes in form of point, for instance, (lat 21.15, lon -58.75) is Tropical climate marked with red. What I want to do is to connect all the same climate point to form a climate zone (polygon), but the same climate can appear in discontinuous regions and hemispheres , which made it tricky to use *¨Aggregate Points (Cartography) tool¨*, *¨Minimum Bounding Geometry¨*, and *¨Points To Line (Data Management) + Feature Envelope To Polygon (Data Management)¨*; since they return disorganized representation which has overlapping.

Do you have any good suggestion with this?

[image: original point climate distribution]
[image: Updated:¨Feature to Raster + Raster to Polygon¨]

Comment: Update:
by using ¨Feature to Raster + Raster to Polygon¨, I managed to have the multiparty polygons 

Comment: You can answer your own question